Suggestion: Sort questions by reputation of the person who asked
Apologies, I feel like I am flooding the meta at the moment. But I think it would be good if you could search questions by, for example, only question for people 10k+ rep. It could (to an extent) solve the problem of high quality puzzles being lost.

Rep might not be the best indicator for puzzle quality. I think what you want is the list of highly scored unanswered questions instead?

Main-meta duplicate.

Worth remembering that (i) high-rep users were once low-rep users - simply filtering by this metric would also automatically give precedence to all the questions they posed as newbies finding their way in the community, which I don't think is what you're really after, and (ii) it's possible in the SE system to get lots of rep by asking vast quantities of low quality questions, which again is not what you want here... There are (unfortunately) multiple obstacles to enabling a feature like this in a helpful way... Sort by votes instead :)
